# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I trained a ImageClassifier model using [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image) and I tried to run the following code on VScode in python 3.8

```
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Load the model
model = load_model('keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('1.jpeg')
#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)
# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

And I got the following errors

```
2021-09-29 11:37:52.587380: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/dropout/temp_rate_is_zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sumuk/OneDrive/Documents/ML/converted_keras/1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import load_model
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import activations
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>     
    from keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing import CenterCrop
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\image_preprocessing.py", 
line 24, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing import image as image_preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.utils import all_utils as utils
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\all_utils.py", line 34, in <module>     
    from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers.core import Lambda
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>    from keras.layers.core.dropout import Dropout
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dropout.py", line 26, in <module> 
    keras_temporary_dropout_rate = tf.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 360, in __init__
    super(BoolGauge, self).__init__('BoolGauge', _bool_gauge_methods,
  File "C:\Users\sumuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
```

Here is the [model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V5Ivpwbka0wIC60IAxLzxeKWBx0TeHNb/view?usp=sharing),
I couldn't find any related solutions online, what should be done?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To run this code , You need to use

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

in place of

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

This issue comes due to mismatch of `tensorflow` and `keras` version available in your system. Make sure you are using same version of `tensorflow` and `keras` or atleast latest `tensorflow 2.7` and try executing the same code again. Let us know if issue still persists.